# Redmine OpenID usage

Tags: openid, redmine

I am a user of Redmine for 4 years and now I was trying to provide access to my user accounts through OpenID. I've manage to install the necessary dependencies and I've used the specified field to fill the openId Url in the user account form.

When I get the login page and enter the https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id I got redirected to a Google page where I can select which of my two active accounts should I grant access to. I do not know which fields will redmine match with the Google response, however I change my login username to my email.

I try both accounts, one a regular Gmail account and the other a Google Apps account. Nothing happens just returns to the login page.

Environment:

```
Ruby version              1.8.7 (i386-linux)
RubyGems version          1.8.10
Rack version              1.1.2
Rails version             2.3.11
Active Record version     2.3.11
Active Resource version   2.3.11
Action Mailer version     2.3.11
Active Support version    2.3.11
Edge Rails revision       unknown
Application root          /var/www/html/redmine
Environment               production
Database adapter          mysql
Database schema version   20110511000000

About your Redmine plugins
Redmine Gitolite Hook plugin       0.1.1
Redmine Light Box plugin           0.0.1
Redmine Backlogs                   v0.6.14
Redmine Auto Done 100%             0.0.1
Mylyn Connector plugin             2.7.5.stable
Redmine Attach Screenshot plugin   0.1.0

Apache + Passenger
CentOS 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Just install [openid_fix plugin](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/openid_fix) and you're good to go.

Moreover, [openid-selector](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/openid-selector) will make things easier ;)

Comment: Installed both of them, the selector was already installed. Now I manage, through looking into the redmine log and grab  "openid.identity"=>"https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlCJoDrEGkXPlpmxxxxxxxxxxxxx". I take that and configured it in my redmine account as open id url. Login now works... well I had to do this also: http://www.redmine.org/issues/7857#note-11

However my actual problem persists since in reality we can simply realize that it's just not implemented such account association feature. Right?

Comment: Using Redmine 1.3.3 stable, don't had such issue. Right now I'm allowing users to register themselves through OpenID, and approving their registration as admin. Then, each user can change their OpenID URL directly from "my account"

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked Google's OpenID isn't fully supported with Redmine. Redmine requires the sreg data to get sent back which I don't think Google does.

I used myopenid.com when I created the OpenID authentication in Redmine.

Answer (score 1):

Google's OpenID works fine with Redmine 1.4.x, there are some issues anyway. 
If you want to register new user using OpenID you won't face any problem other than usability issue.

If you are already registered you can add the identifier manually, BUT you can find that url in your log file, it looks like `"openid.identity"=>"https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawnWGxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3rHTXM` and there is no way for end user to really add that by himself.

Similarly in Drupal, editing your profile will allow you to use a form with OpenID selector to add and authenticate a provider. That form automatically saves the identifier url for you.

Having that functionality in Redmine will be nice.

I will try to come with some code.